# Can words be formed by deriving from just prefix(es) and suffix(es) with no actual root morpheme between?

Tags: morphology, etymology, affixes, word-formation, derivation

I was just looking at a Zulu word entry in Wiktionary that implied it was made from a prefix and a suffix, but there was nothing between them.

Now this could just be sloppy editing of Wiktionary but either way it got me thinking about whether this is a valid word-formation strategy used by any languages.

When I first asked this question I didn't word it in a way that clarified I was asking about word formation. It turns out there are words in several languages which can be analysed on the furface into only affixes, but the examples so far were not originally formed that way, but my more complex processes of adding and dropping morphemes at various stages.

So is this affix-only manner of word formation known to occur? Is it widespread amongst languages?

Comment: Ever shopped at a _Superette_?

Comment: @jlawler: No - is that a word? Before I look it up though I would assume it has a more complex history like market -> supermaket -> superette or somesuch ...

Comment: It's another term for _minimart_, shortened (understandably) from _supermarket-ette_, which I've never encountered. But I've seen it on signs often enough. OMG -- there's a [**Wikipedia page**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superette) for _Superette_.

Comment: @jlawler super- is root here. (even if prefix-derived). There is even separate word "super" meaning "excellent, exceptional".

Comment: Depends on how you parse it. If it must be the case that there is a root, then _super_ is it; on the other hand, if one's faith allows, it's a pre-and-suffix.

Comment: In Mexico it is common to see a class of store called a *minisuper*, which is a word made up of two prefixes, and no suffix or root!  (But as hippietrail guessed in the other case, it has a much more complex and obvious history).

Comment: I'm going to change the wording of the question from "based on" to "derived from" because I wondered about making words from bits rather than analysing words into bits.

Comment: @hippietrail: But what's the difference? I think it all depends on what definitions you choose. You might say *prefix* is such a word, because this *-fix* could be seen as a suffix in English, since you can't use it as a separate word in English with the meaning "bound morpheme" (which would be *affix*).

Comment: @Cerberus: The difference is that I'm interested in the possible processes of word formation active in the world's langauges for this question. This is something deep. I'm not interested in collecting fun factoids about how some words look on the surface for this question. That is something superficial. I'm endeavering in these comments to choose my definitions toward that end. I had never thought of *-fix* as a suffix but if it is then perhaps this is an example.

Comment: @Cerberus: Interestingly, it seems that *suffix* is not derived in part from *-fix* but that *-fix* derives from *suffix* (*suf-* does not appear to be a prefix). However later terms such as *infix* and *circumfix* do seem to have been derived from the suffix *-fix* combined with the prefixes *in-* and *circum-* so in a roundabout way we have turned up some valid examples!

Comment: @hippietrail: Haha OK, I meant something like that. So you are interested in the history of word formation, where a part (any part?) of word was taken together with a part of another word to form a new word, but where neither part was the whole word from which it was taken? Now I'm playing the devil's advocate, but how is this not just a fun factoid?

Comment: Actually I guess I'm wondering about word formation from a Universalist standpoint. Everyone would agree that stem + affix is a very common word formation method and I was wondering if affix + affix is another. I didn't take into account affixes themselves being formed by generalizing an reanalysing from *suffix* and *prefix* to *-fix*. So far the fact that they are quite rare and all seem to be indirect suggests that this is not a general/universal word formation method, but at the same time the whole field of word formation has started to look murkier ...

Comment: Too bad you didn't tell us what the Zulu word is. If you had said "affixes" (only) then I'd say yes, certain demonstratives in a number of Bantu languages. But prefix is defined relative to the root, likewise suffix, so anything with a *pre*fix or a *suf*fix has a root.

Comment: @Flimzy in minisuper, super is the root.

Comment: @anixx the root is "mercado" which has been eliminated.

Comment: @Flimzy no. In THIS word the root is "super". In supermercado, the root may be mercado or supermercado. For instance, Russian has the word "supermarket" borrowed from English, so the whole word is the root in Russian, even though in English it is prefix+root. Russian HAS the prefix "super-" but it has no root "market".

Comment: @Anixx: No. In THIS word, the root is "mercado", and "minisuper" is a shortened form of "minisupermercado"

Comment: @Flimzy doe Spanish have the word "mercado" on its own?

Comment: @Anixx: [Of course it does](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OyRtG0r). It's where you go to buy things.

Comment: @Flimzy does the shortened form "super" exist alone to mean a store?

Comment: For the record, _suffix_ has a prefix. See its [Google etymology](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=etymology+suffix) for details.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. One such word is Russian word *вынуть* "to take out". Here the *вы-* is prefix, *-ну-* is suffix and *-ть* is ending.

The old form of this word was *вынять* which had the root *-ня-*, but later the root was re-analyzed as suffix by analogy with other words (*сунуть*, *дунуть*).

Comment: This is interesting but I wonder how I can amend the wording of my question best to clarify that I don't want to ask about indirect derivations and re analyses but just words actually derived directly from combination only of affixes in the first place.

Comment: Again, that depends on what you mean by "derived directly from". If you can specify what tests could distinguish "direct derivation" from something else, that would be helpful.

Comment: I'm very happy to improve the wording of my questions with the help of others in the comments. Sometimes the idea for a question is clear but getting it into words and keeping it sharp is not so easy for me. I guess tests such as active word formation known to involve just adding prefix(es) and suffix(es) or known etymologies that didn't go through intermediate steps like the *superette* and *вынуть* so far suggested. We can *analyse* both as currently consisting of morphemes which are usually used as adfixes but we know they didn't come about just by adding two adfixes.

Comment: @hippietrail in superette super is root.

Comment: @Anixx: Exactly. Thanks for analysing rightly (-:

Answer (score 4):

In Esperanto there are some words of this kind, e.g., *malina* "male" composed of *mal-* "negation, opposite of" and *-ina* "feminine"

More examples can be found in this answer: https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/407/7

Comment: Idiotic idea. In any natural language it would mean "feminine nay-sayer". If -ina means feminine, then it should mean feminine person everywhere.

Comment: If -ina does not mean a feminine person, it is used as root in this case.

Comment: @Anixx: I think I have zo explain the mal- prefix better:as "opposite of". -in- is a *Movierungs-Suffix* for creating femal versions of male nouns (like and derived from the German suffix -in with the same meaning)

Comment: @Anixx: It's not helpful for this community to dismiss what is a *fact* as idiotic. I wish I could downvote your comment.

Answer (score 1):

No. It is possible for an affix to become a root, as in the mentioned case of *super*, and then to derive new words by attaching prefixes and/or suffixes to it, but that's a different case.

Answer (score 0):

How about *antis* ("those opposed to something")? Unlike the example of "superette" in the comments, where the prefix is shortened from "supermarket," with "antis" the prefix isn't taken from any particular word.

Comment: It is derived from PIE root a̯ent- "end". PIE used roots as "prefixes" in most cases (or one can consider such words having two roots). In this case we simply have the root with a suffix.

Answer (score 0):

Mono-ward is a great example of affixes realising roots where either its prefix or suffix figures as root-to.

Comment: Welcome to Linguistics! Please add some more detail to your answer so that it's not just a one-line comment. If that's not possible, I can convert your answer to a comment until you have enough reputation to do so yourself.

Answer (score -2):

A bit of a cheap shot, but what about 'unable'? Prefix and Suffix with nothing inbetween.

Comment: 'able' is not a suffix, but a root - As in "an able mechanic" (slightly archaic now, but still..)

Comment: @robert interestiongly, this word can be analyzed differently depending on stress. If the stress is on the first syllable, the root is "un". Quite artificial, though.

Comment: I don't think it has any relation to stress. Portuguese and other Romance languages are full of words in which the stress is on suffixes - and even desinences. We even have a word for that - *arrizotônica*, ie, literally, "stress not in the root".